# How do people get out of bacta tanks?

Tags: star-wars

In Empire Strikes Back, we see Luke in a bacta tank. When he's apparently "done", he's whooshed up to the top. Similarly, in Rogue One, Darth Vader is in a bacta tank, and when he has a guest, he's likewise evacuated.

Once they're at the top of the water, how do they get out? When climbing out of a pool, one has to physically hoist themself out of the water and stand up. I imagine that someone recuperating may not have that much strength. Are they assisted to a standing position by a droid?

Comment: It would be very fitting for the med droids to use giant suction cups on the patients' heads, like the way R2 was loaded into Luke's X-wing for the battle of Yavin in ANH.

Comment: In de game Star Wars: Knights of the old republic II, the game begins with a person in a bacta tank. If I remember correctly the bacta tank is emptied, probably through some drain at the bottom, but you don't see the person 'step out' of the bacta tank. It simply is suddenly outside. (it's been a while since i played the game, I might be incorrect).

Comment: Are you looking for a Canon or Legends answer, or either? Inevitably, I actually have a Legends scene for this, although it's not very informative.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I sense a cover-up...

Comment: @Cadence I'm curious about any description or explanation.

Comment: judging by the harness that is worn by the patient, it's likely they are hoisted up, held in suspension above the tank until a "lid" or hatch closes over the tank. They are likely then gently stood on their feet and assisted by a medical droid or attendant. If mobility is needed, they are gently lowered into a chair or mobility device. That's just speculation, but it makes logical sense.

Comment: Take off their hats! No, wait, that's Popes into a Volkswagen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Empire Strikes Back* the implication is that he's simply ***hoisted out of the tank from above***, to the floor above (with the infirmary being set on two levels). This tallies with what we see in the film.

[image]

And in the film's [original junior novelisation.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(junior_novelization))

> Then he saw his friends. Leia, Han, Chewbacca, R2-D2, and C-3PO were gathered on the other side of the medical center’s window. They waved to him. Still groggy, **Luke returned the gesture, then felt his body being lifted out of the tank.**

And in the [Inside the Worlds](http://Inside%20the%20Worlds%20of%20Star%20Wars%20Trilogy) factbook, we learn that the medical centre is set on three (and a bit) level, with the bacta tanks found on the uppermost level with an access space above.

[image]

And the original set photos that show that Luke was to be lowered into the tank from an (unseen) level above.

[image]

---

Moving down into the Legends novels, we see that there are as many kinds of bacta tank as there are authors to write about them, this includes ones that can be lowered into the floor while the patient hangs at ground level.

> The technician droids moved the bacta tank out of position on repulsors and onto a recessed platform in the treatment area. Fi, breather mask still in place, hung more heavily on the suspension straps as the pale blue liquid was pumped away and the cylindrical tank descended below deck level. The droids moved a repulsor gurney into place and maneuvered Fi onto it, placed a temperature sensor somewhere that would have raised a loud objection had he been conscious, then covered him in a padded blue wrapping. The mask was still breathing for him.
>
> <sub><sup>[Republic Commando: True Colors](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Republic_Commando:_True_Colors)</sup></sub>

Comment: I understand that the backstory-fillers had to rationalize the scene in the movie, but it seems silly to have a patient on one floor, and then have them suddenly-ish on another floor that's not easily accessible. What if you pulled them out because you needed to operate on them? I guess droids up top were at the ready. Anywho, this does seem to be the canonical answer.

Comment: @User151841 - No sillier than having the patient lie down on a bed that gets slowly pulled through a hoop while the operator sits in a different room; http://smithassociatesarch.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/06005-WCHOB-Childrens-MRI-5-10_02_08.jpg

Comment: I don't think this comparison is relevant. In the case of an MRI, the operator operates the MRI; they aren't performing on the patient. The patient must be in a small metal tube, because that's where the magnetic field is strongest. Also, there must be no stray objects or metal in a range around the MRI machine; that will interfere with the magnetic field, also. 

Or are you claiming that there is some field around the bacta tank that no object must be in? An image search shows film and illustrations of droid and humanoids standing around the bacta tank.

Comment: @user151841 - If you have a bacta tank, you need some way to access it. Below isn't an option for obvious reasons (splash!) and you don't necessarily want to empty it each time you check the patient, which means that the sides are out. You evidently want the patient upright and to be able to observe them from ground level, which basically means decanting them out of the top. Form follows function.

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to have an entire ceiling around the top edge of the bacta tank? This prevents anyone who is at bacta-tank level from accessing the patient, once they are out, without going up one level. I don't see any nearby stairs or elevators in the images of bacta tanks. If you were a doctor or medical droid examining your patient visually in the tank, or from the consoles at the same level, and you decided "Oh no, they need to come out *immediately* for an emergency procedure!" they all of a sudden on a different floor from you.

Comment: If you have a bacta tank, and the patient needs to exit from it upwards, it seems easy enough to design some sort of platform around the top, with enough space for them to clamber out, perhaps assisted, and maybe even some medical equipment up there. It doesn't make sense to have accessibility completely sealed off and on another floor of the facility.

Comment: @user151841 - Luke's barely conscious. He's not doing any clambering.

Comment: I don't see what relevance that has, either.

Comment: @user151841 - I'm really not sure what you expect me to say. I didn't design the bloody thing.

Comment: I don't expect you to say anything. You gave a good answer and I accepted it.  I was just commenting, not questioning you. But, if you're going to defend the design, and also make irrelevant points and references, I will probably want to throw in my two cents, also.

Comment: @user151841 - You have to remember that this isn't a state-of-the-art facility that's been custom-designed, it's a cave in the side of a hill. In the Rebellion, you make do with what you've got and you don't complain

Comment: One thing that one might reasonably expect you to say could be "Yeah, it does seem like a poor design. Nonetheless, that's what's in the book". I don't know why you feel its your responsibility to defend some backstory that you already said you didn't design.

Comment: @user151841 - Without a comprehensive understanding of the tech and the thinking behind it, it's quite difficult to comprehend why they built it they way the built it. It's like a monkey trying to puzzle out a car engine and complaining that the exhaust is in the wrong place

Comment: Since we lack a comprehensive understanding of the technology, would your comparison of a bacta tank to an MRI then be like a second monkey showing an iPhone to the first, and saying, "That's why the tail pipe has to be there"?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a some references in the *X-Wing* novels, leaving a bacta tank doesn't seem to be all that dramatic. In *The Bacta War* (fittingly) Corran Horn leaves a tank under his own power as soon as he's done recovering:

> A gentle tug on the breathing mask he wore caused Corran to look up. He saw a round hatch through which light came and a silhouette of a human head and shoulders through it. Kicking his legs, Corran made his way to the surface of the tank. He removed the breathing mask and hauled himself out through the hatch.

Likewise in *Solo Command* Piggy saBinring leaves a tank without much fanfare:

> He glanced up to see the top hatch opening. He kicked himself upwards and moments later emerged into real air for the first time in many days.

Of course, these are both fit fighting men in the prime of life, so it's not too surprising that they can extricate themselves from the tank without much difficulty. The tank is kept at neutral buoyancy, with the bacta medium at the same density as the patient's body - hence the characteristic way people float in the tank - so it shouldn't be difficult at all to propel oneself upward.

If a patient needed help getting through the hatch itself, it could probably be provided. In Corran's case he was met by a technician right on top of the tank, indicating that at least some models are spacious enough for people to move around on top; presumably it would be just as easy to have someone standing by to lift the patient out, or to maneuver a crane or similar into position.

Recuperation isn't likely to be a problem for the average patient, as restoring their injuries swiftly and completely is the whole point of bacta. Corran for instance had broken a number of bones including his pelvis but was fully able to walk around afterwards. I don't know whether receiving a prosthetic (as Luke did) would cause more difficulty in leaving the tank immediately afterwards.